# Drawing 3 cards of same suit and 2 of a different suit

Tags: probability, combinatorics, card-games

What is the probability of having 3 cards of the same suit and $2$ cards of the same suit (but a different suit than the first three) in a $5$ card hand from a standard $52$ card deck?

What is the difference between solving this problem using approach (1) and (2). Assuming we divide both by ${52 \choose 5}$

$(1)$

$$
{4 \choose 1}\cdot{13 \choose 3}\cdot{3 \choose 1}\cdot{13 \choose 2}
$$

$(2)$

$$
{4 \choose 2}\cdot{13 \choose 3}\cdot{13 \choose 2}
$$

Why can't I just pick the two suits all at once? Why do they have to be separated out? In the first approach I don't have the problem of duplicates. A {10_Hearts, J_Hearts, K_Hearts, 3_Spades, Q_Spades} doesn't equal {3_Spades, Q_Spades, X_spades, 10_Hearts, J_Hearts}

Answer (score 1):

**Revised to match corrected question:** If you pick the two suits at once, you don’t distinguish the case of (say) $3$ hearts and $2$ clubs from the case of $3$ clubs and $2$ hearts. Thus, you ought to get exactly half of the right answer, and indeed you do:

$$\binom42=6=\frac12\binom41\binom31\;.$$

If you want to start out by choosing the two suits, you can, but then you have to choose which is to get $3$ cards: all that can be done in $\binom42\binom21=12$ ways. That’s exactly what you get if you first choose the $3$ card suit and then the $2$-card suit from the $3$ remaining suits: $\binom41\binom31=12$. And you still have to choose the cards from the suits, so you still get factors of $\binom{13}3$ and $\binom{13}2$.

Comment: Hi Brian, Thank you again for your help. The (3C1) was a typo meanst to write (13C2), just edited in the question.

Comment: @jessica: You’re welcome; I’ve revised the answer to match what you intended.

Comment: So the problem with the second approach is I didn't designate which suit gets the the 3 cards and which gets the 2 cards. But how does the (2C1) take that into account?

Comment: @jessica: There are $\binom42$ ways to pick the set of $2$ suits to be used. Then you have to pick one of those $2$ to be the $3$-card suit, and there are $\binom21$ ways to do that. (Alternatively, there are $\binom21$ ways to pick one of the two to be the $2$-card suit. But you mustn’t do **both**, because once you’ve decided which of the two suits is the $3$-card suit, then you have no choice left: the other suit is automatically the $2$-card suit.

Comment: I see so in another similar question: What is the probability of picking $3$ same numbered cards and $2$ same numbered cards (A triple and a pair so $AAABB$). If I decide to pick the two same cards , (13C2). I have to pick one of the two categories and designate it to the $triple$ and the other to the $pair$. Getting (13C2)(2C1)(4C3)(4C2). Alternatively I could just pick each individually (13C1)(4C3)(12C1)(4C2).

Comment: @jessica: Yes, that’s right.

Comment: Brian thank you so much!! Your my hero!!

Comment: @jessica: You’re very welcome; I’m glad that it helped.

Answer (score 1):

Select the suit with 2 cards (1 out of 4), select their values (2 out of 13), then select the suit with 3 cards (1 out of the remaining 3) and then the 3 values (3 out of 13) for a total of

$$
\binom{4}{1} \cdot \binom{13}{2} \cdot \binom{3}{1} \cdot \binom{13}{3} = 267696
$$